# What does マナーもいっしょに「携帯」 mean?

Tags: meaning

What does マナーもいっしょに「携帯」 mean?

This is the title of an article in J501 that talks about how people should watch when and where they use their cellphones. I get the text but can't make sense of the title. Is there any way to say this in natural English?

I also can't make sense of the related マナーもいっしょに携帯しましょう. "Let's have our manners also cellphone together" is my best guess, but it's definitely not very usable English.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder It sounds 100% natural.

Comment: Hint: Look up 携帯 in a dictionary. It has another meaning than “cellphone.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto So a pun along the lines of "Carry your manners [with your cell phone]"? Just confused grammatically more than anything.

Comment: I think you got the meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From goo辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/66822/meaning/m0u/)

> けい‐たい【携帯】
>
> ［名］(スル)
>
> 1. 身につけたり、手に持ったりすること。「非常食を―する」
> 2. 《「ケータイ」と書くことが多い》「携帯電話」の略。

"携帯する" as a verb, means to carry something portable, like a mobile phone (see number 1 above).

The sentence is a bit of a [pun](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/136473/meaning/m0u/%E3%83%80%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AC/), where it uses the word "携帯" to not mean "mobile phone" (where it can, and very often does), at the same time as the adjective "いっしょに" is referring to the omitted and implied "携帯" (in this case, meaning "mobile phone").

The sentence basically means: "don't forget your manners" or ["carry your manners along with your mobile phone"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29646/what-does-%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%97%E3%82%87%E3%81%AB-%E6%90%BA%E5%B8%AF-mean#comment61572_29646).